# Python Pandas: Style column header

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

I am using [pandas styler](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.html#pandas.io.formats.style.Styler) to give some columns a background color, based on the name of the column header.
While this works as intended, the background color of the column header doesn't change.

Here is the part in my script where thy style is applied:

```py
def highlight_col(x):
    if x.name in added_columns:
        return ['background-color: #67c5a4']*x.shape[0]
    elif x.name in dropped_columns:
        return ['background-color: #ff9090']*x.shape[0]
    else:
        return ['background-color: None']*x.shape[0]



old = old.style.apply(highlight_col, axis=0)
```

Is there a way to apply the [style.apply()-function](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html#pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply) not only to the cells below the column header, but the complete column including the column header?

Edit:
For clarification here is a screenshot of the excel output:
[screenshot of excel output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahFay.png)

"Header 2" should have the same background color as the cells below it.

Comment: To do the column headers look at using `df.style.set_table_styles`.

Comment: Can show a sample image of your expected output?

Comment: @ScottBoston in my undrestanding the set_table_styles changes all headers, but i only want to change specific ones.
Also I added a screenshot.

Comment: Okay.  I added a solution.

Answer (score 9):

Okay, I think I figured out a way to handle formatting a column header using html 'selectors':

Using much of your code as setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame('some value', columns=['Header1','Header2','Header3'], index=np.arange(12))
added_columns = 'Header2'
dropped_columns = 'Header1'

def highlight_col(x):
    if x.name in added_columns:
        return ['background-color: #67c5a4']*x.shape[0]
    elif x.name in dropped_columns:
        return ['background-color: #ff9090']*x.shape[0]
    else:
        return ['background-color: None']*x.shape[0]


col_loc_add = df.columns.get_loc(added_columns) + 2
col_loc_drop = df.columns.get_loc(dropped_columns) + 2

df.style.apply(highlight_col, axis=0)\
  .set_table_styles(
     [{'selector': f'th:nth-child({col_loc_add})',
       'props': [('background-color', '#67c5a4')]},
     {'selector': f'th:nth-child({col_loc_drop})',
       'props': [('background-color', '#ff9090')]}])
```

Output:

[image]

*Note:  I am using f-string which is a Python 3.6+ feature.*

Comment: Thank you, but sadly it doesn't work.
The exported excel file still only colors the column without the header.
Do you know about any other way?

Comment: Yep, this appears to be bug.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.vstack()` to stack the column names like below and create a fresh dataframe to apply the function, then export to excel with `header=False`:

Using @Scott's data and piR's function,
Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame('some value', columns=['Header1','Header2','Header3'], index=np.arange(12))
def f(dat, c='red'):
    return [f'background-color: {c}' for i in dat]
```

---

You can do:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.vstack((df.columns,df.to_numpy())),columns=df.columns).style.apply(
                  f,subset=['Header2']).to_excel('file.xlsx',header=False,index=False)
```

---

Output of excel file:
[image]