# How to to add Background color to a specific column of pandas dataframe and save that colored dataframe into that same csv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a CSV file I add the code to process data on it and know how to save the final dataframe to the same CSV by using `to_csv` method. The problem is I want to add the background color to some of the columns, how can I do it?

[image: Example data with colored columns]

Comment: csv doesn't save color information about columns.  You'd need to save the color information as another column or within the column name and have a custom csv reader to parse it out.  I'm trying to say that csv doesn't do what you want it to and in order to make it do it anyway, it'll get ugly.

Comment: can you tell me how to add colour to the entire specific column including column_name and it's all Values of a dataframe ? means how can I get mentioned image like output in a Dataframe

Comment: try using/googling `pd.ExcelWriter`, saving the results in .xlsx will allow you to color the column background.

Answer (score 6):

I strongly suggest reading the [guide in the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html)
To see an example where column names are styled see [this post by Scott Boston](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55263917/2336654)

---

#### `style` with `apply`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1], [2, 3]], ['A', 'B'], ['X', 'Y'])

def f(dat, c='red'):
    return [f'background-color: {c}' for i in dat]

df.style.apply(f, axis=0, subset=['X'])
```

[image]

---

#### Multicolor

```
columns_with_color_dictionary = {'X': 'green', 'Y': 'cyan'}

style = df.style
for column, color in columns_with_color_dictionary.items():
    style = style.apply(f, axis=0, subset=column, c=color)
style
```

[image]

---

#### Save color meta data in the column name

```
df.rename(columns=lambda x: f"{x}_{columns_with_color_dictionary.get(x)}") \
  .to_csv('colorful_df.csv')

df_color = pd.read_csv('colorful_df.csv', index_col=0)

cmap = dict([c.split('_', 1) for c in df_color])
df_color.columns = df_color.columns.str.split('_', 1).str[0]

style = df_color.style
for column, color in cmap.items():
    style = style.apply(f, axis=0, subset=column, c=color)
style
```

[image]

---

#### Save as `HTML`

```
from IPython.display import HTML

columns_with_color_dictionary = {'X': 'yellow', 'Y': 'orange'}

style = df.style
for column, color in columns_with_color_dictionary.items():
    style = style.apply(f, axis=0, subset=column, c=color)

with open('df.html', 'w') as fh:
    fh.write(style.render())

HTML(open('df.html').read())
```

[image]

Comment: i tried the above pieces of code but when i print, the pycharm give me a normal dataframe not colored df like you showed above the same thing in IDLE also