# How to make column names bold and Fill the colors to the column header

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How to make column names Bold in Pandas Data-frame while highlighting the Header.

### Datatframe Below..

```
Name        Sir Name    Country Age
James       Pullman     Holland 38
Ricardo     Jacob       Holland 28
Arie        Tilman      Holland 27
Ruben       Juneja      Holland 29
Naveen      Therry      Holland 26
Audery      Cuenin      Holland 27
```

Expected:

[image]

OR

Fill the color to the whole background

[image]

Comment: Would appreciate any comment before someone place a minus vote?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this what you were asking, but I provided an example below, if this is what you are asking,

Comment: Thanks David, i perceive  that it makes column names bold, however i want to highlight the column name header.

Comment: I think here is necessary set css in style object.

Comment: @jezrael, thanks for the making it duplicate, but i show this links. and another 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57805803/how-to-to-add-background-color-to-a-specific-column-of-pandas-dataframe-and-save/57806265#57806265  but i did nit get it how to do it .. just learning around, i have edited the question before you marked it duplicate.

Comment: @kulfi - yes, only change `css` to bold, it is problem?

Comment: I need to highlight the whole column header as well. if you can guide that will be good.

Comment: Edited my question, may be that will helpful to get some answer.

Comment: @kulfi - OK, do you test solution from dupe? It is what you need?

Comment: i did  `s = df.style.set_table_styles([{ 'selector': 'th', 'props': [('background-color', 'yellow'), ('color', 'cyan')]}])` when i did `print(s)` i get `<pandas.io.formats.style.Styler object at 0x7f7766f6eda0>` .

i did not get table printed.

Answer (score 0):

@kulfi, either 1) it is not a **dataframe** or 2) you are using `print`. I coded an example of the data below. If you copy and paste this it will be bolded. Notice how I just type `df` instead of `print(df)`. If you use other common features such as `pd.read_csv('filename.csv')`, then it will automaticlly be imported as a dataframe. Not sure what the issue is for you, but I hope this helps:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['James', 'Ricardo', 'Aire'],
                   'Sir' : ['Pullman', 'Jacob', 'Tilman']})
df
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @David for the hint and placing an answer.. +1 for the support and way around

Comment: No problem @Kulfi -- what was the specific problem for you? Was it 1) 2) or something else? I would like to point you to some good resources depending on your answer.

Comment: many thanks for your inputs and answer, i have updated the qustion , sorry for making confusion but your answer make my doubt clear.