# Color Specific Headers in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to set background color of specific headers in dataframe

Here is the Original Dataframe:

[image: 1]

and here is what i want:

[image: 1]

I have tried this code so far, but it doesn't work:

```
df1.style.set_table_styles(
       [{
           'selector': 'th',
           'props': [('background-color', 'red')]
       }])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pandas: Style column header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55243717/python-pandas-style-column-header)

Answer (score 0):

This should help you!

```
import xlwings as xw
df1.to_excel("file.xlsx",index=False,header=False)
wb = xw.Book("file.xlsx")

# color is set with an rgb value 
wb.sheets['Sheet 1'].range('A').color = (169,169,169)
```

This basically writes to excel ad then changes the format as needed. You can change the color to any RGB values you would want to.