# Change the color of some headers in a dataframe and export to excel

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I have two lists of headers and a dataframe like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
list1 = ["A","B","C"]
list2 = ["E","F","G"]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list1 + list2)
# Change columns color logic
df.to_excel("test.xlsx")
```

I want to change the color of the headers in list1 to get something like this:

[image: Expected Output]

It can be the font or background color, but it must be changed with pandas.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55243717/python-pandas-style-column-header)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pandas: Style column header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55243717/python-pandas-style-column-header)

Comment: Not really, I tried with that code and does not work for me. The difference is that in that question you want the whole column of one color, and only two specific headers, while I want only the headers of one color, and I have a list of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible option :

```
# df.insert(0, "Year", [2021, 2022, 2023]) to match your example!

(
    df.style.apply_index(
        lambda x: np.where(
    x.isin(list1), "background-color: #8db4e2", ""),axis=1)
    #.to_excel("...", index=False) # uncomment to make an Excel
)
```

[image]